# Port forwarding wireless tethering without using a VPN

Tags: tethering

There is a [very similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/port-forwarding-for-wireless-tethering), but the only answer suggests running an openVPN server etc., which is not what I'm looking for. I need to use the phone and only the phone.

So, I need to port forward my phones wifi hotspot to a computer on the network but can't find an option to do it in the standard settings. The port I need to forward is port 80. The reason for this is to be able to access a web-server from outside the network.

The phone is a Samsung GT-I8150 running Android 2.3.6. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: If you already know there's a duplicate... I don't want to sound rude, but then you shouldn't open it nevertheless. If you're not satisfied with the answers available to it, the StackExchange way of prodeeding is placing a [bounty](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) (and include a description what it is set for), not open a duplicate question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Port forwarding for wireless tethering](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/port-forwarding-for-wireless-tethering)

Comment: Isn't it better to formulate the question to my specific needs instead? Since I can't just go ahead and edit and replace his question? Sometimes this "one question per topic" thing is exaggerated. Just a few minutes ago I was told my question was a duplicate because there was an answer to a completely unrelated question that had a link in it that fit my needs. So I'm extra grumpy about the subject at the moment. Ofcourse a troll uses the exact link I provided to point it out officially. :P

Comment: If the other question and its answers won't work for you, then the thing to do is make sure you include _why_ in your quasi-duplicate question. I've attempted to make that distinction clear here; you might want to edit your question to reinforce it further. I think (now) the questions are sufficiently different to not close this as a duplicate. Of course, that's not to say that there is a viable solution to what you're looking for.